# How to get a list of TFS build agents via API/Powershell?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm building a tool for checking disk space on the TFS Build servers. I could just input a manual list but for longterm use, it's best if I could import the list of build servers from somewhere. I've connected to TFS with the following code

```
add-type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll"
$TFSURL = "http://tfs:8080/tfs/"
$TFS = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($TFSURL)

$buildServer = $TFS.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
```

Not sure how to proceed from here. I haven't been able to find much relevant documentation or my googling skills are rusty.

Comment: Rather than building your own utility, you might just want to look at https://tfsworkspacescleaner.codeplex.com/

Comment: That looks useful. But I don't have authority to include this so I'll bring it up with my boss. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're looking for the Agents, and to get those you need to get the controllers that they're associated with, so you need to run the `QueryBuildControllers()` method of your `IBuindServer` object.

```
$buildControllers = $buildServer.QueryBuildControllers()
$buildControllers.Agents
```

I found this by doing a search for Client.IBuildServer on Google, and going to the first link to MSDN. From there I just looked for a method that would find all of something that looked relevant to servers, and saw the QueryBuildControllers method, followed it to see the return objects had a property named Agents, which should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Perfect! I'm not very used to TFS and Microsoft management tools so I didn't see that Controllers were the ones handling agents. Much to learn.

Comment: To be honest with you, I had no idea either =) It was a learning experience for us both!